# Catch Javascript page errors in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

We have an up and running extension already built in.

1. We load a Javascript through cdn on the web page.

< script src="cdn/51617/explore.js" type="text/javascript">

Now if there is any error in this script I want to display that error in the extension.

I can do messaging and pass the errors to the extension. Thats not the concern the prime objective here is to only try to **log** errors caused by the explore.js script & should not include any other errors.

I have tried window.onError() but it catches all errors on the page.

Comment: There's probably no way to do it unless you download the script contents, wrap its code in try{} catch(e){} and insert it via script element's textContent. Although maybe adding an `error` event listener on the script element itself could help...

Comment: @wOxxOm
Then how tools like sentry.io are able to log these errors? 
Also, there's a correction above. 
I dont need to catch errors but rather log those errors.    

      a. https://sentry.io/share/issue/89e29de350024278b06f6f544c610acd/
      b. https://sentry.io/share/issue/dbc91c8dba5646e4b18fe0699b1d2df8/
      c. https://sentry.io/share/issue/d53faca0919749f8a0b4221ed1a4c8e4/

Comment: Ah, maybe you an check `error.stack`